# improve jQuery code

Tags: jquery, html

I have this function to call a component to my principal container

Here is my html

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="photos">
    </div>
</div>
```

And my js file

```
$(document).on("ready", call_data);

function call_data(){
    var snippet = "<div class='image'><div class='image-body'><img src='img/59.jpg' height='320px' ></div><div class='image-title'><i class='fa fa-map-marker'></i> Silvania, Colombia <img src='img/png/co.png' alt='colombia'></div><div class='image-author'><div class='author'><i class='fa fa-camera-retro'></i> by Valeria Bayona</div></div></div>"
    $("#photos").append(snippet);
};
```

Can I do something like:

```
var snippet = "<div class='image'></div>";
snippet.append("<div class='image-body'>");
...
```

Comment: `var snippet = $("<div class='image'></div>");` FYI, `$(document).on("ready",handler);` is non conventional method to bind ready handler, that way you lose the promise behaviour of the pseudo ready event which makes ready event to be fired even document is already 'ready'. This `$(document).on("ready", call_data);` should be written: `$(call_data);`

Comment: Let me see if I understand, it must be: $(document).on("ready", $(call_data)); ?

Comment: No, it should be: `$(call_data);` or `$(document).ready(call_data);` but not: `$(document).on("ready", call_data);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in order to use the jQuery `append` function, **the object you are using must be a jQuery object**. You would have to do something similar to your `call_data` function:

```
var snippet = $( "<div class='image'></div>" );
snippet.append("<div class='image-body'>");
```

---

In your example, you are tring to call `append` on a string object. The string object doesn't implement an `append` method:

```
var s = "my string";
s.append( "another string" ); // TypeError: Object my string has no method 'append'
```